Nginx always redirect to https
I have three docker containers running on my raspberry. First is homeassistant which is created via default docker compose. Second is nginx connected to third container node app. When I access homeassistant in my local network on the other machine via http everything goes well. When I try to access my node app I receive ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in my browser.
Ping receives data from my raspberry. But curl 192.168.100.82:80 throws web exception. Curl 192.168.100.82:80 on raspberry redirects to https://192.168.100.82:80
My nginx.conf setup in my container is:
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 192.168.100.82;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.100.82:3000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}

Changing proxy_pass to localhost doesn't change anything.
My docker-compose:
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: /my-node-path
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    privileged: true
    network_mode: host
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /my-node-path/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - app
    restart: unless-stopped
    privileged: true
    network_mode: host

Firewall ufw at this point is inactive
How can I bypass it? Thank you for your help

If you delete network_mode: host from both containers, then you can proxy_pass http://app:3000/ using the other container's name as a host name.

Right now I don't receive an error while using curl on another machine but it still redirects me to https:

curl 192.168.100.82:80
Found. Redirecting to https://192.168.100.82/

With -i flag I receive below header response:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.27.0
Date: Tue, 25 Jun 2024 12:50:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 45
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Location: https://192.168.100.82/
Vary: Accept
Why Location is on https?
